# Translate "let static 2 = argument 1" to VM code

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine, jvm-arguments, high-level, nand2tetris

Translate "let static 2 = argument 1" to VM code.

VM code (the answer):

> push argument 1
>
> pop static 2

**My question**

Aren't we forgetting `let`. Shouldn't we push another argument 1 to the stack, and then pop it to local 2 too? In order to preserve the "local type".

https://www.coursera.org/learn/nand2tetris2/lecture/z1wbL/unit-1-3-vm-abstraction-memory-segments
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to pop too local 2. In jack a let statement can be for field varibles too and does not have to necessarily be for local variables.

Push argument 1 would put the value in index 1 in argument segment on top of the stack which is 12.

Then you pop the top value from the stack into static 2 which is highligted in your picture

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `let` in the pseudocode statement `let x=y` indicates to the reader that a name/value binding is about to occur, but `let` itself is not a variable.

You could read it as `imagine x=y` or `assume x=y` instead of `let x=y` if you prefer.